# how do I display ads inside my recyclerview

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-recyclerview

So basically, my RC displays the ads very well, but I have issues with my items, i.e., when I  have only 1 item, it doesn't get displayed, same as three items; the second Item gets skipped, and only two Items get displayed.

Here is the link to my gist: https://gist.github.com/Ttoml33/586fa25ba5c06c4d517cd1f1cb074ba1

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65007009/android-get-correct-item-position-after-admob-native-ads-are-added-to-recycler-v/65031512#65031512